# How to inherit methods from a parameter in your classes constructor

Tags: javascript, inheritance

So I'm exporting an object from one file and I'm trying to inherit all of it's methods and add

```
function childClass (model) { 
this.model = model
}

childClass.prototype.foo1 = function(){
this.model.Something1();
}

childClass.prototype.foo2 = function(){
this.model.Something2();
```

}

Ideally when someone instantiates an object from childClass I would like for it to inherit all of the methods from the base model object the class is using, just so that instead of calling obj.model.function1 I could just call obj.function1.

Comment: So then why don't you inherit from your model class instead of wrapping it?

Comment: Search for "delegation". By the way, did you mean to say `this.model.Something1()` (with a dot between `model` and `something1`?

Comment: I did thanks was kind of just free typing in the text editor

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for a delegation pattern, which you could implement as:

```
defineDelegate(delegatee, method) {
    childClass.prototype[method] = function() {
        var delegatee = this[delegatee];
        return delegatee[method].apply(delegatee, arguments);
    };
}
```

Now you can say

```
defineDelegate('model', 'Something1');
defineDelegate('model', 'Something2');
```

This will need to be cleaned up and generalized, but I hope you get the idea.

If for some reason you want to delegate **all** methods on `model`:

```
Object.keys(modelClassPrototype)
    .filter (function(k) { return typeof modelClassPrototype[k] === 'function'; })
    .forEach(function(k) { defineDelegate('model', k); })
;
```

Comment: just out of curiosity how would this be different then doing this.Something1 = model.Something1 in the childClass constructor?

Comment: That won't work because it won't pass across the `this` properly. (It would also put the property on every single instance of `childClass`.)

Comment: model.something1 is a function instead of a method, if you assigin the function directly to this object, the context of the function will changed to the instance of the object created by ChildObject, instead of model, and you probably dont want this

Answer (score 0):

you are actually ask how to mix the model in childclass

```
function childClass (model) { 
 Object.keys(model).forEach(function(key) {
   childClass.prototype[key] = model[key].bind(model);
 });
}

var m = { create: function() {console.log(this);}};

var c = new childClass(m);
c.create();
```

the `this` context of the create method will be model, if you don't want to bind this to model, than remove bind function

Comment: have to admit that @torazaburo's solution is much better